# how to refresh html table and other data in the same script with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need your help.

In javascript, I call a php page with AJAX to create a map (openstreetmap) and just after I call an other php page with AJAX to refresh a HTML table.
It works but I want to use a single AJAX call to create my map and refresh mys table in the same time. Is it possible and if yes can I have your help ?
The first PHP page and the second PHP page use exactly the same request Mysql to retrieve data.

This is my javascript code :

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: './api/req1.php',
 data: { Zdate: Zdate
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                ZMesmarkeurs.clearLayers(); // on supprime tous les markeurs avant d'en ajouter
                var markerArray = []; // on déclare le tableau qui va recevoir les markeurs
                var dataResult = JSON.parse(data);
                /* on créer les markeurs si on en a */ 
                if (dataResult) {
                    for (var key in dataResult) {
                        if (dataResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            var LatClient = dataResult[key].LatClient;
                            var LongClient = dataResult[key].LongClient;    
                            if (LatClient && LongClient){
                                /* on affiche le markeur avec l'info client dans la popup */
                                L.marker([LatClient, LongClient]).addTo(ZMesmarkeurs).bindPopup('retour GPS').bindPopup(dataResult[key].Nom_Clients+ " "+dataResult[key].Prenom_Clients+"<BR>"+dataResult[key].Adresse+"<BR>"+dataResult[key].Code_postale+" "+dataResult[key].Ville);
                                markerArray.push([LatClient, LongClient]); // on ajoute les markeurs dans le tableau
                                //map.fitBounds([[dataResult[key].LatClient, dataResult[key].LongClient]]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                map.fitBounds(markerArray); // on centre la carte sur les markeurs
                }
            }
        });
        // recherche de tous les rendez-vous de la journée indiquée
        // pour les afficher dans le tableau de gauche
        $.ajax({
            url: "./api/Req2.php",
            type: "GET",
            cache: true,
            data: { ZdateRDV: ZdateRDV },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#TableGPSTech').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Is it possible to use only one AJAX call to create my map an refresh my html table ?

I hope I have been clear.

Thank's a lot for your help.

REGARDS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
const getMap = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: './api/req1.php',
    data: { Zdate: Zdate },
    cache: false
});

const getTable = $.ajax({
    url: "./api/Req2.php",
    type: "GET",
    cache: true,
    data: { ZdateRDV: ZdateRDV }
})

$.when(getMap, getTable).done(function(mapResult, tableResult) {
    ZMesmarkeurs.clearLayers(); // on supprime tous les markeurs avant d'en ajouter
    var markerArray = []; // on déclare le tableau qui va recevoir les markeurs
    var dataResult = JSON.parse(mapResult);
    /* on créer les markeurs si on en a */
    if (dataResult) {
        for (var key in dataResult) {
            if (dataResult.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var LatClient = dataResult[key].LatClient;
                var LongClient = dataResult[key].LongClient;
                if (LatClient && LongClient) {
                    /* on affiche le markeur avec l'info client dans la popup */
                    L.marker([LatClient, LongClient]).addTo(ZMesmarkeurs).bindPopup('retour GPS').bindPopup(dataResult[key].Nom_Clients + " " + dataResult[key].Prenom_Clients + "<BR>" + dataResult[key].Adresse + "<BR>" + dataResult[key].Code_postale + " " + dataResult[key].Ville);
                    markerArray.push([LatClient, LongClient]); // on ajoute les markeurs dans le tableau
                    //map.fitBounds([[dataResult[key].LatClient, dataResult[key].LongClient]]);
                }
            }
        }
        map.fitBounds(markerArray); // on centre la carte sur les markeurs
    }
    $('#TableGPSTech').html(tableResult);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It is not possible to use just one call AJAX to create my map and refresh the html table ?

Comment: No, and I don't know what value it would bring if you could. An ajax call is a http request to a specific URL. You cant have one call go to 2 urls. I thought you meant you wanted to act on the results once both calls were complete

Comment: each ajax calls one script (in your case PHP script) and waits for its asynchronous data return.  Since you are calling two PHPs and wait for their asynchronous returns (respectively), you need two ajax

Comment: In fact, your question really could only be interpreted one way - and this is the solution. Otherwise it's like asking 'can I load 2 webpages in my browser with two URLs at the same time' :) Hope this answer helped.

Comment: In my map I want use custom marker with different colors.
For example :
- on map for the person "Z" 2 markers red with number 1 and another number 2. For the person "X" one marker blue with the number 1.
- in the html table, first line with marker red and number 1, second ligne with marker red with number 2, third line with marker bleu with the number 1
So I must study an other solution if I can't use one call ajax to refresh two différents objects.
Thank a lot.

Comment: Actually, this is the first step to doing what you're describing. Since to accomplish this, you'll need both ajax results together... Though I don't completely understand your end result, I am pretty confident that this is the start. Your best bet is to post a new question with this new infomation, and use this solution as the starting point. You'll attract more attention to it as a new question and will have the first part of the puzzle sorted out. If you do that, pls mark this as the solution to the question you posted here. Best of luck!